# reduce javascript

Tags: javascript

Я сейчас пытаюсь разобраться как работает `reduce`. Наткнулся на такую задачу. Есть массив который содержит несколько объектов.

```
let mas = [{ age: 44, name: 'Sam' }, { age: 22, name: 'Jack' }];
```

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает объект следующего вида

```
obj = { 'Sam' : 44, 'Jack' : 22};
```

вот что у меня получается

```
let mas = [{ age: 44, name: 'Sam' }, { age: 22, name: 'Jack' }];

function f() {
  let obj = {};

  return obj = mas.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
    return curr.name = curr.age
  }, {});
}

console.log(f());
```

подскажите, что не так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо вернуть объект, который получен из предыдущей итерации добавлением поля `curr.name` со значением `curr.age`.

Чтобы было так:
`{} -> {'Sam' : 44} -> {'Sam' : 44, 'Jack' : 22}`

Вы же в строке `curr.name = curr.age` возвращаете значение `curr.age`. То есть результатом выполнения всегда будет `age` последнего элемента массива.

```js
let mas = [{
  age: 44,
  name: 'Sam'
}, {
  age: 22,
  name: 'Jack'
}];

const obj = mas.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = curr.age;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

```js
let mas = [{
  age: 44,
  name: 'Sam'
}, {
  age: 22,
  name: 'Jack'
}];

const obj = mas.reduce((acc, curr) => ({[curr.name]: curr.age, ...acc}), {});
const obj2 = mas.reduce((acc, curr) => Object.assign({[curr.name]: curr.age}, acc), {});

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj2);
```